# Firebase cloud functions failing to build on getDocs import

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up some firebase cloud functions. I haven't been able to get anywhere yet because deploying my functions breaks when I try to import firestore methods.

Here's my code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const {
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    getDocs
} = require("firebase/firestore");

// Get all documents from a collection
exports.getAllDocuments = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {
    let collectionName = data.collection;

    console.log(collectionName);
});
```

The **getDocs** import seems to be the issue here, but I can't figure out how to fix the problem.

Here's the error provided:

> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.*

In the logger, the messages provided are:

> Could not load the function, shutting down

and

> Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated.

I've installed firebase/firestore dependencies with

```
npm install --save @firebase/firestore
```

Please note: I'm using firebase v9 so if I can do this with const/require instead of import, that would be ideal. I don't use **getDocs** yet in my code but I will in the future. This code snippet has been edited down to help me find the source of the issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the web client SDK (firebase/firestore) when you should be using the Firebase Admin SDK.  The web client SDK is not really meant for use in nodejs backends like Cloud Functions.

Remove the getDocs import you have now entirely (and uninstall firebase/firestore because you won't need it for Cloud Functions).  Then, review the documentation on using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to import Firestore APIs and use them.  Be sure to use the node.js samples from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#node.js_5) (not the web samples).

Comment: Thanks so much Doug! That was exactly the problem. I shouldn't have been using the web client SDK in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

For your imports, use:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
```

and remove:

```
const {
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    getDocs
} = require("firebase/firestore");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this didn't work for me. The base problem was as Doug described.